# Proving two probability matrix multiplication is still a probability matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

There is a n by n probability matrix $Q = Q_{ij}$ and $Q_{ij} \ge 0 \quad(i, j = 1,2,...,n)$ with $\sum_{j=1}^nQ_{ij} = 1 \quad (j = 1,2,...,n)$.

I am curious about how to prove that $Q^2 = QQ$ is still a probability matrix, and I have tried to use the deduction method below,

**n = 2**
$$
  \begin{align*}
      Q^2 & = QQ = \begin{pmatrix} q_{11} & q_{12} \\\ q_{21} & q_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} q_{11} & q_{12} \\\ q_{21} & q_{22} \end{pmatrix} \\\ & = \begin{pmatrix} q_{11}^2 + q_{12}q_{21} & q_{11}q_{12} + q_{12}q_{22} \\\ q_{21}q_{11} + q_{22}q_{21} & q_{21}q_{12} + q_{22}^2 \end{pmatrix} \\\
  \end{align*}
$$

From above, I can clearly see that the sum of rows remains at $1$ if I add each row:

$$
  \begin{align*}
  q_{11}^2 + q_{12}q_{21} + q_{11}q_{12} + q_{12}q_{22} & = q_{11}(q_{11} + q_{12}) + q_{12}(q_{21} + q_{22}) \\\ & = q_{11}\cdot1 + q_{12} \cdot 1 = q_{11} + q_{12} = 1
  \end{align*}
$$

I think this can work out, but I am not sure if I should use this way since I think there is a better way than this, like from the property of stochastic matrix that always has eigenvalue $1$.

Can anyone give me some advice about thinking about this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can verify the following two properties are true for $Q$ and any of it's powers (so in particular for $QQ$). (a) The entries of are non-negative and (b) vector $(1, 1, \dots 1)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, that is a crucial idea. I have tried to digger deeper into the eigenvector of a stochastic matrix, and it looks like this attribute is related to proving that all other eigenvalues are less than $1$ as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $v=(1,\dots,1)^T$. $Q$ is a probability matrix if and only if its entries are all nonnegative and $Qv = v$. This second condition is a restatement of the fact that all rows must sum to one.

Suppose $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are probability matrices. Multiplying and adding nonnegative numbers gives you nonnegative numbers. So $Q_1Q_2$ has nonnegative entries. Furthermore: $$(Q_1Q_2)v = Q_1(Q_2v)=Q_1v=v$$

So, $Q_1Q_2$ is also a probability matrix.

Comment: First, thank you for your post. I reviewed Prof. Gilbert's video regarding the Markov matrix once again and did get more on this topic. However, I faced a question that is, when I tried to compute from a random 2 by-2 matrix, I found that if I want to follow your proof, it looks like the columns should sum up to $1$ instead of the rows, does this implies that I should use $Qv = v$ in this case?

Comment: @Sonamu You are correct that in _"... $Q^Tv = v$. This second condition is a restatement of the fact that all rows must sum to one_" should be "columns sum to 1". This typo is not essential, you simply choose the right condition and the correct expression for it. Andrew and Stefan Lafon showed you the right direction: use $(AB)x=A(Bx)=Ax=x$. If eigenvalues confuse you, forget about them; as Andrew said, _"that's not otherwise important"_.

Comment: Yes, I was mixing up conventions when I originally wrote this. I made everything consistent now.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Yes, thank you for your clarification, I was a little bit confused with the basic theorem of four spaces in LA. I should review those concepts once again.